# Books to learn how to use matlab, mathematica, octave and latex

Tags: reference-request, math-software

I need some good books to learn how to use these efficiently:

1)Matlab
2)Mathematica
3)Octave
4)LaTeX

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Simply Googling each term above, and searching for the proprietors' sites (first two cases) will get you to websites where you can download extensive user manuals and/or locate very helpful and free tutorials. Look for links including "mathworks" (Matlab) and "wolfram" (Mathematica) in the URL, if you want material published by the proprietors. See also  [*Introduction to Matlab*](http://etools.fernuni.ch/matlab/matlab1/en/html/startpage.html).

In the case of GNU [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), you'll find a link to *support*, where you can download an $800$-page [reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/octave.pdf), which I've included here to facilitate your access.

For $\LaTeX$, you might want to check out the website [latex.project.org/guides](http://latex-project.org/guides/) website where you'll find resources (free) under the heading "Documentation". I'll include a link to *[The (Not so) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)* (pdf) to facilitate your access.

Answer (score 1):

For Matlab, can I suggest the app, obtainable through the Play store?

See here...

[Matlab tutorial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andromo.dev445013.app566347)

Answer (score 0):

For Mathematica, "Schaum's Outline" is a good introduction (and reasonably priced).

For Latex, the book I find most useful is "First Steps in Latex" by Gratzer.  I'm sure there are more advanced books, but my needs are pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

For Octave, I can suggest [GNU Octave for beginners](http://jordi.platinum.linux.pl/octave/Jesper%20Schmidt%20Hansen%20-%20GNU%20Octave%20for%20Beginners.pdf)